# Error with apache http client java program

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-commons-httpclient

I have got an issue with a simple program to get the data from an url using 'apache http client (4.5.2 version)'.

Please find the code and the error below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String username = "user";
        String password = "pwd";
        String urlString = "xyz.com?a=b&c=d";

        org.apache.http.client.HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
        org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials(
                username, password);
        request.addHeader(new BasicScheme().authenticate(creds, request));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            result.append(line);
        }
    }
```

**Error:**

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message>
```

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

I did not experience the error above, but I was able to run this code sample with no error after adding "http://" to the beginning of the given

```
String urlString = "xyz.com?a=b&c=d";
```